# Django - warn user before doing a migration

Tags: django, database-migration

I'm writing a django model migration which will delete all the existing objects (of a model) in the database.
Is it possible to warn the user before actually migrating? 
I want to remind the user to backup the data before actually doing the migration.

can I take a a `raw_input()` from the user and then continue if he actually wants it?

How do I cancel a migration during the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do anything you want in a [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) operation - that includes asking for user input and raising an exception to cancel the migration.

The migration won't be marked as applied until all operations succeeded. Just make sure that the `RunPython` operation asking for confirmation runs before any other operation in the same migration file. If you don't do this, and the user cancels the migration, it could leave the database in an inconsistent state with a partially applied migration.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you for the answer :)